# Sveltekit: different in|out FLY transition (vertical and horizontal) based on screen width

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-transition

I'm learning Sveltekit and i am trying to figure out how i can implent two differently oriented in:fly/out:fly based on the width of the screen (mobile and monitor for example).

Something like:
IF on monitor screen (min-width: 640px) then in:fly from the left
ELSE (if on mobile phone) in:fly from the top

This is an example of my code at the moment:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';

    /* Navigation menu */
    const navigation = [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            href: '/'
        },
        {
            title: 'About',
            href: '/about'
        },
        {
            title: 'Projects',
            href: '/projects'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            href: '/contact'
        }
    ];
</script>
<nav class="navigation" in:fade={{ duration: 100 }} out:fade={{ duration: 100 }}>
    <ul
        class="navigation__content"
        in:fly={{ x: -1000, duration: 300 }}
        out:fly={{ x: -1000, duration: 300 }}
    >
        {#each navigation as navItem}
            <li class="navigation__page">
                <a href={navItem.href}>{navItem.title}</a>
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I am not quite sure how i could implement something like this, i was thinking about a #if statement.
I searched the web but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a store that programmatically matches a media query and switch out the transition arguments accordingly, e.g.

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export function mediaQueryStore(query) {
    const store = writable(false);
    
    onMount(() => {
        const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(query);

        const onChange = () => store.set(mediaQueryList.matches);
        mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', onChange);
        onChange();

        return () => mediaQueryList.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
    });

    return { subscribe: store.subscribe };
}
```

```js
const small = mediaQueryStore('(max-width: 600px)');
```

```html
<div transition:fly={$small ?
  { x: -1000, duration: 300 } : 
  { y: -1000, duration: 300 }}>
```

(If in/out animations are the same, you can just use `transition:...`)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e18fa24850a84cb5906c72f4be413c8b?version=3.59.1)

Comment: I tried this but i have no idea why it doesn't work on my code, you can check it my REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/aa45f1f273e241c5b30cc1bc5adf8716?version=3.59.1
The little square is the menu button.

Comment: The evaluation of the media query happens after the transition has already started. Would recommend setting such a store as a context at a high level so it can be used everywhere, that way it will also evaluate much earlier.

Comment: [Fixed REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b8bbfc5f110c4b1a9d0ba19a40354a7c?version=3.59.1)

Comment: It's working but i still get an error (and well i'm confused, because it works anyway):
`Cannot use 'screen' as a store. 'screen' needs to be an object with a subscribe method on it.
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(store: SvelteStore<any>): any', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SvelteStore<any>'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(store: SvelteStore<any> | null | undefined): any', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SvelteStore<any> | null | undefined'.ts(2769)`

Comment: This on the Navbar.svelte component.
The setContext is in `+layout.svelte`

Comment: That is just a type error, if you use TS you need to assert the type when using `getContext`, e.g. `getContext<Readable<boolean>>('...')`.

Comment: Thank you very much H.B. i've added `import type { Readable } from 'svelte/store';` and modified `screen` to `const screen = getContext<Readable<boolean>>('screen-store');`, now everything works without errors

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to watch the window width via the innerWidth binding [(tutorial)](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-window-bindings) and set `x` and `y` accordingly

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7281af348ef649f99b4a4a341ee56087?version=3.59.1)

```
<script>
    import {fly} from 'svelte/transition'

    let innerWidth
    const threshold = 640
    $: x = innerWidth >= threshold ? -100 : 0
    $: y = innerWidth < threshold ? -100 : 0

    let nrs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

    function add() {
        nrs = [...nrs, nrs.length] 
    }
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth />

<div id="page">
    <button on:click={add}>add one</button>
    <button on:click={() => nrs = [0,1,2,3]}>reset</button>
    innerWidth: {innerWidth}
    <div id="nrs">
        {#each nrs as nr (nr)}
        <div class="nr"
                 in:fly="{{x, y}}"
                 >
            {nr}
        </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 2rem;
        background: lightgrey;
    }
    #nrs {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: .5rem;
    }
    .nr {
        width: 4rem;
        height: 4rem;
        display: grid;
        place-content: center;
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }
    :global(body) {
        padding: 0;
    }
    :global(*) {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I am always a bit sceptical about these bindings because internally they rely on the `resize` event which can fire many times per frame, potentially causing performance issues in other contexts. But given that Svelte updates the component UI/reactive statements at most once per frame that should not be an issue...

Comment: @H.B. yeah, I guess your media query approach is nevertheless the *'cleaner'* and preferred option

Comment: I would like to thank you for your solution too Corrl, appreciated