# Apply different transition on smaller screens

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-transition

I would like to apply a different transition when the device width is below a certain threshold. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76505639/13994538), but instead of just passing different transition parameters per breakpoint, I want to apply a different transition.

For example applying a `fly` transition by default, but then on screens smaller than 600px in width, apply a simple fade transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions are just functions, so you can just move the size check into a custom transition function and call `fly`/`fade`, something like:

```js
function fadeOrFly(node) {
    return isScreenSmall() ? fade(node) : fly(node, { y: -100 });
}
```

```html
<div transition:fadeOrFly>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ba319e2f08634767bbba31886e210cff?version=3.59.1)

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: One note: if you change the view size while the element is in view, then you want to change which out transition will be applied by using `in` and `out` instead of `transition`. REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/256d99b74bbe462db006e7e1b84e268f?version=4.2.9

I believe the explaination is that Svelte must evaluate `transition` before showing the element, while it can wait to evaluate `out` until it needs to transition the element out.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with CSS variables (custom properties).

This lets you specify what transition you want from your CSS using regular media queries (vs switching based on `isScreenSmall()` or similar functions).

Set some custom property that designates the transition you want to use (using any identifier you like), then switch the transition based on that.

Example of a drawer that slides in from the right on large screens, and the bottom on small screens:

```
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';

    function responsiveTransition(node) {
        const dir = getCssVar('--dir', node); // some utility function
        switch (dir) {
            case 'bottom':
                return fly(node, { y: '100%', duration: 300 });
            case 'right':
                return fly(node, { x: '100%', duration: 250 });
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="drawer" in:responsiveTransition out:responsiveTransition>...</div>

<style>
    .drawer {
        --dir: bottom;
    }
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        .drawer {
            --dir: right;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as @brunnerh, but using `in` and `out`, as it makes the transition a little bit more robust to viewport change while the element is in view.

```js
function fadeOrFly(node) {
    return isScreenSmall() ? fade(node) : fly(node, { y: -100 });
}
```

```html
<div in:fadeOrFly out:fadeOrFly>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/256d99b74bbe462db006e7e1b84e268f?version=4.2.9